# Admob Live Wallpaper on Display?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Is there a way to display an admob ad every hour or so right on the live wallpaper?

Comment: This is diabolical. Pure evil, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean a general live wallpaper rather than your own.

I don't think it is possible but even if it is technically possible, you would have to figure out how to display it. For example, consider an animated live wallpaper which repaints itself completely for each frame.

I recommand using the notification (or if you must the Toast) mechanism since it is much less intrusive and you can use it regardless of the current live wallpaper.